# How to enable harmony in Coffeescript?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, ecmascript-harmony, appjs

Here is how I run my js code:

```
node --harmony ./data/app.js
```

Now I want to move to the CoffeeScript. So I try to run  it like that:

```
coffee ./data/app.coffee
```

And it fails. How can I pass this `--harmony` option?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To pass args through, you can use the `--nodejs` argument:

```
coffee --nodejs --harmony ./data/app.coffee
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it still prints me an error: `Error: AppJS requires Node is run with the --harmony command line flag
`

Comment: It's still about lack of `--harmony`. So I think this option doesn't go to the node, but to the coffee, which doesn't recognize it...

Comment: @ciembor Looks like I got the order of the arguments wrong, updated.